# Exit code of command substitution in bash local variable assignment

Tags: bash, exit-code, local-variables, command-substitution

How can I check the exit code of a command substitution in bash if the assignment is to a local variable in a function?
Please see the following examples. The second one is where I want to check the exit code.
Does someone have a good work-around or correct solution for this?

```
$ function testing { test="$(return 1)"; echo $?; }; testing
1
$ function testing { local test="$(return 1)"; echo $?; }; testing
0
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you look at the man file for `local` (which is actually just the BASH builtins man page), it is treated as its own command, which gives an exit code of `0` upon successfully creating the local variable. So `local` is overwriting the last-executed error code.

Try this:

```
function testing { local test; test="$(return 1)"; echo $?; }; testing
```

**EDIT:** I went ahead and tried it for you, and it works.

Comment: Thanks, like always, right after I posted my question I found the answer myself which comes out as the same you suggest. I just have too less of a reputation to answer my own questions before 8 hours have passed.
But `man local` gives me the man page of `LOCAL(8postfix)` manpage, so not too useful. But I found it on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_varname.3D.24.28command.29

Comment: Another source of information would be `man bash`. `local` is mentioned under the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" section.

Comment: The `help` command returns documentation on built-in commands. See `help local`.